# Downgrading from Storyboard to XIB

Tags: xcode, button, storyboard, xib

So I understand that I can not use storyboard on anything less then 5.0. I have finished my App using storyboard only so am very basic to code.

I am going to re-create my app using XIB, I will create a new XIB file for each of my storyboards.

Want I would like help with is the code I need to cross-fade between each XIB. There will a button linking each XIB.

What do I need to add to ViewController.h and where do I put the code into ViewController.m

Thanks a lot for your help.

Bryce

Comment: *why* do you want to go from Storyboard to XIB?  If your client / employer is pressuring you to have iOS 4.0 support, tell him iOS 6.0 is likely to be out soon and that means even *less* people are going to be running with iOS 4 going forward.  And the people who stay back on older OS's are ones who are not likely to want to pay for an app.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.

```
- (IBAction)changeViews:(id)sender
{
ModalViewControllerTwo *modalViewControllerTwo = [[ModalViewControllerTwo alloc] init];
modalViewControllerTwo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:modalViewControllerTwo animated:YES];
}
```